# How to get access token after token expiry by using signalR negotiation Azure function in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, signalr, azure-signalr

I am using @microsoft/signalr package installed in Angular 11 application. I am getting 401 error once the access token got expired after 1 hour. Is there a way to get access token renewed after the token expiration something like by using refresh token in Angular 11?

**signalr.service.ts:**

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

orderMessages: Subject<any> = new Subject();
saleMessages: Subject<any> = new Subject();
     
private getConnectionInfo(): Observable<SignalRConnectionInfo> {
   return this.http.get<SignalRConnectionInfo>('http://localhost:7071/api/SignalRNegotiationFunction');
}
    
init() {
   this.getConnectionInfo().subscribe(info => {
      let options = {
           accessTokenFactory: () => info.accessToken
      };
   this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .withUrl(info.url, options)
       .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 1000, 5000, null])
       .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)        
       .build();
   this.hubConnection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
   this.hubConnection.off('notifyresult');
   this.hubConnection.on('notifyresult', (data: any) => {
      if(data == "Orders") {
       this.orderMessages.next(data);
      }
      else {
       this.saleMessages.next(data);
      }
   });
 });
}
```

**Azure Function:**

```
public static class SignalRNegotiationFunction
{
   [FunctionName("SignalRNegotiationFunction")]
   public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
       [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "notification")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
            return connectionInfo;
    }
 }
```